# C# Tasks and Use of Async/Await keywords

Tags: c#, .net

In the following code snippet since I am not able to use async/await keywords, is this method make behave synchronously?

```
public Task<IQueryable<Student>> Handle(GetStudentByIdRequest request)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(repository.GetAllCalfSubjects(student => student.studentId.Equals(request.studentId)));
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Comment: If you look at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,11a386e7d7cae64a), you can see that `Task.FromResult` creates an already completed task.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have shown us?

Comment: Why do you create a Task, if you don't want to await it? Just use `public IQueryable<Student>......`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is this method make behave synchronously?

Yes, it will always behave synchronously. `GetAllCalfSubjects` executes synchronously and then its result is wrapped up in a `Task<T>` by `Task.FromResult`, and that task is then returned. All of this is synchronous.

It doesn't make much sense to return an `IQueryable<T>` wrapped up in a `Task<T>`. `IQueryable<T>` already has asynchronous APIs attached to it, so it's normal to just (synchronously) return that type:

```
public IQueryable<Student> Handle(GetStudentByIdRequest request)
{
  return repository.GetAllCalfSubjects(student => student.studentId.Equals(request.studentId));
}
```

Then the calling code can call `ToListAsync` or whatever they want to do.